# Add Fields to Django form not present in model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a student model to keep data of students.

**Models.py**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    roll_no = models.IntegerField(editable=True, blank=False, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default='1900-01-01', blank=True)
    admission_no = models.IntegerField(default=roll_no)
    admission_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    student_cnic = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    father_cnic = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    grade = models.ForeignKey('school.SchoolClasses', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Student Form looks like

**Forms.py**

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    extra_fields = ['school']

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['roll_no', 'name', 'date_of_birth', 'admission_no', 'admission_date', 'student_cnic', 'father_cnic',
                  'mobile', 'grade']


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(Row(Column('roll_no', css_class='form-group col-md-6'),
                                        Column('admission_no', css_class='form-group col-md-6'), ),
                                    Row(Column('date_of_birth', css_class='form-group col-md-6'),
                                        Column('admission_date', css_class='form-group col-md-6'), ),
                                    Row(Column('name', css_class='form-group col-md-3'),
                                        Column('student_cnic', css_class='form-group col-md-3'),
                                        Column('father_cnic', css_class='form-group col-md-3'),
                                        Column('mobile', css_class='form-group col-md-3'), ),
                                    Row(
                                        Column('school', css_class='form-group col-md-3'),
                                        Column('grade', css_class='form-group col-md-3'),
                                    ),
                                    Submit('submit', 'Add Student', css_class='btn btn-primary'), )

        self.fields['date_of_birth'].widget = forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
        self.fields['admission_date'].widget = forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
```

`

The school field is just to Filter the result for grade field to return only those grades present in the selected school

But i am getting an error
`KeyError: "Key 'school' not found in 'StudentForm'. Choices are: admission_date, admission_no, date_of_birth, father_cnic, grade, mobile, name, roll_no, student_cnic."`

Answer (score 0):

You have to define **school** field in form. Because **school** is not a field of model **Student**. Add add **school** in fields of **Meta** class. Your form will be like following:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    school = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=School.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['roll_no', 'name', 'date_of_birth', 'admission_no', 'admission_date', 'student_cnic', 'father_cnic',
                  'mobile', 'grade', 'school']


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(Row(Column('roll_no', css_class='form-group col-md-6'),
                                        Column('admission_no', css_class='form-group col-md-6'), ),
                                    Row(Column('date_of_birth', css_class='form-group col-md-6'),
                                        Column('admission_date', css_class='form-group col-md-6'), ),
                                    Row(Column('name', css_class='form-group col-md-3'),
                                        Column('student_cnic', css_class='form-group col-md-3'),
                                        Column('father_cnic', css_class='form-group col-md-3'),
                                        Column('mobile', css_class='form-group col-md-3'), ),
                                    Row(
                                        Column('school', css_class='form-group col-md-3'),
                                        Column('grade', css_class='form-group col-md-3'),
                                    ),
                                    Submit('submit', 'Add Student', css_class='btn btn-primary'), )

        self.fields['date_of_birth'].widget = forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
        self.fields['admission_date'].widget = forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
```

Don't forget to import **School** model in forms:

```
from school.models import School
```